# Upgrading without loss of hardware-functionality?

Tags: upgrade

I try to upgrade 12.10 LTS to 14.04 LTS and I'm wondering whether I should save some specific files which are needed to configure my hardware correctly.
I know upgrading should only touch system files - but that's the problem.
I don't know which files are needed  to control buttons and stuff.
Thanks a lot for help

joe

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to save any files to properly upgrade. Upgrading only updates the software sources and packages to the latest version. Configuration files are generally not touched, or simply replaced by the new version.

Only if you made changes to some configuration files yourself, you might want to make a backup in case it gets overwritten by the upgrade (although the upgrader should notify you in that case)